# checkbox_oncheckedchange event not firing in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to populate a gridview from a datatable in the code behind. In one of the columns dynamic checkboxes are generated. This is the code for gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdAdDetails" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ad Id" DataField="Ad Id" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ad Type" DataField="Ad Type" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ad">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <img src='<%#Eval("Ad") %>' height="150px" width="150px" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ad Url" DataField="Ad Url" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            **<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAds" Checked='<%#((bool)Eval("Active"))%>' runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkAds_OnCheckedChanged" />**
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Active" DataField="Active" />--%>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Node Id" DataField="Node Id" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

and this is the datatable code from the code behind:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Ad Id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ad Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ad", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ad Url", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Active", typeof(bool));
            dt.Columns.Add("Node Id", typeof(string));
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[temp].[somename]", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nodeId", 1088);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adType", 0);
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dr["Ad Id"] = reader[0].ToString();
                    dr["Ad Type"] = reader[1].ToString();
                    dr["Ad"] = reader[2].ToString();
                    dr["Ad Url"] = reader[3].ToString();
                    dr["Active"] =Convert.ToBoolean(reader[4]);
                    dr["Node Id"] = reader[5].ToString();

                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            con.Close();
            grdAdDetails.DataSource = dt;
            grdAdDetails.DataBind();
```

checkbox onchanged code:

```
public void chkAds_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int selRowIndex = ((GridViewRow)(((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent)).RowIndex;
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)grdAdDetails.Rows[selRowIndex].FindControl("chkAds");

            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                //some code here
            }
        }
```

When I check/uncheck the checkbox, the **OnCheckedChanged** event is not firing. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: If I am right, you should add to the checkbox attributes the following AutoPostBack="true".

Comment: Initially I added it...but only the page reloads again and again but still it doesn't hit the code behind

Answer (score 0):

I have added a sample here plz chk it.

**view:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
                            OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                       <asp:checkbox id="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("fpath")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Eval("desc1")%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdesc" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("desc1")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Modify" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit">
                                    <ControlStyle Width="50" />
                                </asp:CommandField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String fname, fpath, desc;
    String spath;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "";
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            //Check File is available in Fileupload control and then upload to server path
            fname = FileUpload1.FileName;
            spath = @"~\Uploaded\" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            fpath = Server.MapPath("Uploaded");
            fpath = fpath + @"\" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            desc = TextBox2.Text;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fpath))
            {
                Label1.Text = "File Name already exists!";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(fpath);
            }
            //Store details in the SQL Server table
            StoreDetails();
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            LoadGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Please select file!";
        }
    }
    void StoreDetails()
    {
        String query;
        query = "insert into fileDet(fname,fpath,desc1) values('" + fname + "','" + spath + "','" + desc + "')";
        sqlcon.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlcon.Close();
        LoadGrid();
    }
    void LoadGrid()
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from fileDet", sqlcon);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        dt.Clear();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        sqlcon.Close();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        LoadGrid();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        LoadGrid();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        String ID;
        ID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from fileDet where ID='" + ID + "'", sqlcon);
        sqlcon.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(dt.Rows[0][2].ToString())))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(dt.Rows[0][2].ToString()));
            }
        }
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("delete from fileDet where ID='" + ID + "'", sqlcon);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlcon.Close();
        LoadGrid();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string ID;

        ID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        FileUpload flname = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("FileUpload2");

        if (flname.HasFile)
        {

            fname = flname.FileName;
            spath = @"~\Uploaded\" + flname.FileName;
            fpath = Server.MapPath("Uploaded");
            fpath = fpath + @"\" + flname.FileName;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fpath))
            {
                Label1.Text = "File Name already exists!";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                flname.SaveAs(fpath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Please select file!";
        }

        TextBox desc1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtdesc");
        string query;
        query = "update fileDet set fname='" + fname + "',fpath='" + spath + "',desc1='" + desc1.Text + "' where ID='" + ID + "'";
        sqlcon.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlcon.Close();
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        LoadGrid();
    }
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)chk.Parent.Parent;
       // lblmsg.Text = GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        //lblmsg.Text = "Hello";
    } 
}
```